# Select in a select from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to make a query to another table and add the result to the current one as a new record if there is no record with an id in it, but if the current table has a value with such an id then add the value.

table 1:

| id | name | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | alex | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | tom | 2022-01-01 |

table 2:

| id | name | pass |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | alex | 111 |
| 3 | mitch | 222 |

expected result:

| id | name | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | alex | 2022-01-01 | 111 |
| 2 | tom | 2022-01-01 |  |
| 3 | mitch |  | 222 |

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment. Please share what have you tried, what research you did and what specific problems you encountered. Please read [ask] in [help]. Your question in this form is more of a work order than a question, please show at least some effort you did before writing the question. (Hint: FULL OUTER JOIN).

Comment: Perhaps [`MERGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) would be good approach, since you need both `INSERT/UPDATE`. But yes, this is exam question. Come back when you get stuck with your own solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a merge results for both the tables so you query will be

`select * from table1  full outer join table2 on table1.(some column name) = table2.(some column name)`

here some column name represents you id in table1 and table2 respectively.
so your query will be

`select * from table1  full outer join table2 on table1.id = table2.id`

Comment: This approach will not do any INSERT/UPDATE into the 1st table, which is the main problem in the question.